# How can i check to see if my "npx hardhat compile" is working properly

Tags: frameworks, solidity, hardhat

### First of I'm building a motorbike rental application and need to get the code compiled for contract deployment BUT every time I put "NPX hardhat compile" using hardhat framework this comes up,

√ What do you want to do? ·
Quit
PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\motorbike-application> npx hardhat compile
888    888                      888 888               888
888    888                      888 888               888
888    888                      888 888               888
8888888888  8888b.  888d888 .d88888 88888b.   8888b.  888888
888    888     "88b 888P"  d88" 888 888 "88b     "88b 888
888    888 .d888888 888    888  888 888  888 .d888888 888
888    888 888  888 888    Y88b 888 888  888 888  888 Y88b.
888    888 "Y888888 888     "Y88888 888  888 "Y888888  "Y888

Welcome to Hardhat v2.13.0

? What do you want to do? ...

> Create a JavaScript project
> Create a TypeScript project
> Create an empty hardhat.config.js
> Quit

---

I don't see WHY this comes up if I already used this menu selection when I ran "npx hardhat" to initially create the project at the start of the project. Now, when I run "npx hardhat compile" directly in the contracts file I get:

"Your project is an ESM project (you have "type": "module" set in your package.json) but your Hardhat config file uses the .js extension.

Rename the file to use the .cjs to fix this problem.

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH19 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces"

Any suggestions or thoughts maybe i start over the code? or redownload everything?

I tried running in inside contracts and nothing.

Tried the regular way and nothing.

I'm expecting it to compile

Answer (score 0):

show your package.json
If you have installed any node related package lower the version of it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).